# Including a directory when Publishing a WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf

The problem I am having is with the Publish setting in Visual Studio. The directory I am trying to include is getting flattened and there are conflicting files causing two problems.

I have managed to bundle individual files easily but I also need to include a directory (containing files) when my app builds.

The reason being is that Unity (which I'm embedding) requires a "UnityBuild_Data" directory (which also has sub directories of its own).

So my Published app needs to have:

```
(WPF app files, i.e AppCore.exe & it's  files)
UnityBuild.exe
UnityBuild_Data/

... etc
```

So while I have figured out how to include the UnityBuild.exe, I can't seem to include the directory unity requires (UnityBuild_Data). Because of this, Unity complains that the Data directory is not there. If I manually go to where my app is installed and place it there, it all works fine.

What seems to be happening is that all the files in the directory are getting flattened and put at the root level.

I have edited the project file (.csproj) to include this:

```
<ItemGroup>
<Content Include="$(SolutionDir)Dependencies\**\*">
<Link>%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</Link>
</Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

In this scenario, the Dependencies folder would be in the solution directory and include a sub directory called UnityBuild_Data/

```
Solution/
-- Dependencies/
--  -- UnityBuild_Data/
            ** dlls and other files in here **
```

Extra info:

After I try to build even just to check if there are any problems I get, this error, which I believe is because 1) the files are flattened & not put into a sub-directories 2) resulting in dlls named the same:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     Unknown build error, 'Inheritance security rules violated while
>   overriding member:
>   'System.Uri.System.Runtime.Serialization.ISerializable.GetObjectData(System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo,
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext)'. Security
>   accessibility of the overriding method must match the security
>   accessibility of the method being overriden. Line 8 Position
>   87.'  AppCore.UI  C:\Users\userj\Source\Repos\AppCore\src\AppCore.UI\App.xaml 8

My project builds okay if I remove any of the conflicting dlls inside UnityBuild_Data/Managed

But the problem remains that when I "publish" the app through visual studio (creates an installer), everything gets flattened and the "UnityBuild_Data" directory is missing (unity complains with an error).

Potential solutions, but not ideal:

1) Zip up the directory and then extract in the app code somehow?

2) Create the directory and move over files (renaming the ones that conflict)

Comment: In VS, if you just click on the directory, and/or files, you should see under properties an option that will let you pick either copy, copy if newer or do not copy. Select copy if newer. Option is called "Copy to Output Directory"

Comment: @Hozikimaru I'm not seeing that option for the directory or it's sub-directories. I am seeing it for any files inside the directory. I tried setting them all to "copy if newer" but I am still getting the same problem with building. The only option for directories is: "Folder Name" and it can't be changed. Thanks for the idea though.

Comment: @JasonAddFour You can add an empty placeholder file in that folder, and copy it to output using it's properties.